# Array Map Function Error

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, error-handling

I am getting a error saying this code needs a parentheses but every time so far it hasn't came up as a problem before here is the full error message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')'
```

Here is my code:the first line is where is says the error is:

```
$escaped_values = join(',', array_map(function($v) {
return "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($v) . "'";
}, array(
$_POST['account_status'],
$activation_key,
$_POST['first_name'],
$_POST['last_name'],
$_POST['email'],
$_POST['username'],
$password,
$_POST['phone_number']
)));
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? [Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) were introduced in 5.3.0, so if you have an older version of PHP, you'll run into this error. On another note, have you considered using PDO's [parameterized queries](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)? Easier, cleaner and universally understood.

Comment: @Alfabravo I am running a later version (5.2.17)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are using an older version of PHP that doesn't support closures. They are available as of PHP 5.3

Example using an old fashioned named function:

```
function escape($v)
{
    return "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($v) . "'"; 
}

$escaped_values = join(',', array_map('escape', array(
    $_POST['account_status'],
    $activation_key,
    $_POST['first_name'],
    $_POST['last_name'],
    $_POST['email'],
    $_POST['username'],
    $password,
    $_POST['phone_number']
)));
```

However you'd better do it using PDO as suggested by NullUserException...

Comment: Yeah I am just realized that I am Running 5.2.17

Comment: Use an old fashioned named function, and pass the name of that function as a string to the first parameter of `array_map`, see the examples in the manual: http://php.net/array_map

Comment: so how would that look as code?I looked at php.net but still don't really get it.I also need it to be a mySQL escaped string.

Answer (score 2):

[Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) were introduced in 5.3.0, so if you have an older version of PHP, you'll run into this error. Another way to do what you're doing is it to use [`create_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php):

```
array_map(create_function('$v', 'return "\'" . mysql_real_escape_string($v) . "\'";')
           , $yourArray)
```

But a far better alternative would be to use PDO and [parameterized queries](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php):

```
// example:
$sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO your_table
                          (activation_status, first_name, last_name)
                             VALUES (?, ?, ?)');

$params = array($activation_status, $_POST['first_name'], $_POST['last_name']);
$sth->execute($params);
```

Easier, cleaner and universally understood. Your parameters will be automatically escaped.

Comment: PDO is probably a kajillion times easier than using `mysql_real_escape_string` everywhere.